# Can't see F-Curve in Dope Sheet

Tags: animation

I am not sure why I can't see the F-Curve in Dope Sheet.  And when I hover over the Wrench symbol, it says "F-Curve modifiers are disabled."  How to fix?

Here's what I have:
[image]

And here's what was shown in an animation tutorial:
[image]

Comment: F curves are in the Graph Editor, you are in the Dope Sheet, to switch from Dope Sheet to Graph Editor, press Ctrl Tab

Answer (score 1):

The *Dope Sheet* and the *Graph Editor* are different Editors.
Dopesheet shows keyframes only.
The Graph Editor will show f-Curves

You can toggle/switch from one to the other by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Or to access the Graph editor directly by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>